# Quadrics and lines

Tags: geometry, quadratics, surfaces

Having a quadratic equation like this : 
**Q**= $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2-3z^2-4x+6z=0 \\ 
\\ 
(x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb R^3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
How can I write a cartesian equation of a line on **Q** and a line on **Q** passing from the origin  ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $x$, $Z$ and $z$, really supposed to be different?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(at,bt,ct)$ be a point on the line.

Thus, for all real $t$ we have: $$a^2t^2+b^2t^2-3c^2t^2-4at+6ct=0,$$ which gives
$$a^2+b^2=3c^2$$ and
$$-4a+6c=0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got two these  lines:
$$(3t,\sqrt3t,2t)$$ and
$$(3t,-\sqrt3t,2t)$$